# I'm having a problem with my angular11 http PUT method. All others work in angular except PUT. All of them work in Postman

Tags: angular, http

```
export class UsersService {

  corsProxy = 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/';

  constructor(
    private _http: HttpClient,
  ) { }

  _getAllUsers(): Observable<User> {
    return this._http.get<User>(`${this.corsProxy}http:/api/usersSelect/select`);
  }

  _createUser(user: User): Observable<User> {
    return this._http.post<User>(`${this.corsProxy}http://api/usersInsert/update`, user);
  }

  _deleteUser(id: number) {
    return this._http.delete(`${this.corsProxy}http://api/usersDelete/delete?id=${id}`);
  }

  _editUser(id: number, user: User) {
    console.log('User in SERVICE: ', user)
    return this._http.put<User>(`${this.corsProxy}http:/api/usersUpdate/Update?id=${id}`, user);
  }
}
```

Comment: What error you see?

Comment: there is no error to follow in the console...the network log shows a 200 res with my payload attached

Comment: the code above is exactly how it sits in my project...for some reason it left out the type castings when i uploaded it to stack overflow, sorry...I'm newish here. But that's how my code looks and it still doesn't work

Comment: the return in postman is my array with the user I've edited but in Angular it's empty

Comment: Please post more complete code. For example: How are you calling the service and how are you consuming the respose?

Comment: I'm just trying to add the components file now thanks...but in short I inject my service into the component and call on the edit method passing the id and user object in